# How to detect MouseDoubleClick on Calendar BlackoutDates?

Tags: .net, wpf, calendar, double-click

In my WPF/C# app, I have a `Calendar` control, with a range of `BlackoutDates` set. I also want to handle `MouseDoubleClick` events, but I can't see how to determine the user has double-clicked on a blackout date - the date returned to the event handler in that case is the most recently-selected valid (i.e. non-blackout date) date.  How can I "ignore" double-clicks on these `BlackoutDates`?

EDIT:
XAML:

```
<Calendar MouseDoubleClick="Calendar_MouseDoubleClick"/>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Calendar_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (myCalendarBlackoutDatesCollection.Contains(/* what goes here? */))
    {
        return;  // ignore doubleclick
    }
    // execution continues here
}
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: @MattL. not sure how that will help, but I'll add something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle the `MouseDoubleClick` of each individual `CalendarDayButton` by defining a `CalendarDayButtonStyle`:

```
<Calendar x:Name="cal">
    <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="cal_MouseDoubleClick" />
        </Style>
    </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
</Calendar>
```

---

```
private void cal_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarDayButton button = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarDayButton;
    DateTime clickedDate = (DateTime)button.DataContext;
    if (!cal.BlackoutDates.Contains(clickedDate))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No blackout date was clicked!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! However... I am also using `Interaction.Triggers` for the MVVM pattern, and am not figuring out how to effectively move the Handler to the View Model, and not have it in the code-behind. Suggestions? Or should I open up another question

Comment: Yes, please. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.

Comment: But to give you a lead; Write an attached behaviour that invokes the command. Or simply invoke the command from the code-behind event handler in the view. You can't apply an interaction trigger in a Style.